# Error al ejecutar un script para subir archivos por FTP a un servidor externo - 'PORT' Command not implemented

Tags: php, pdo, ftp

Tengo una script para subir archivos por FTP a un servidor externo a través de PHP, que está generando errores y aunque cambie al puerto pasivo, o de **FTP_Binary** a **Ascii** o inverso, sigue generando errores.

Al poner **ftp_pasv()**, sigue apareciendo el error y se adiciona el siguiente

error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se generan muchos puertos en Apache, lo mismo para el hosting, así que el problema no estaría en el xampp local, sino, es general.

El script me devuelve este error:

> 'PORT' Command not implemented

, y cuando pongo el modo pasivo de php me devuelve esto:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in

y los puertos extra.

**mi codigo**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
function upload($file, $author){
    $id = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $format = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $db = dbConnect();
    $save = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO files (id, author, format) values (:id, :author, :format)");
    $save->bindParam("id", $id);
    $save->bindParam("author", $author);
    $save->bindParam("format", $format);
    $save->execute();


$conn_id = ftp_connect("servidor") or die ("Cannot connect to host");
ftp_login($conn_id, "pwd", "pwd") or die("LOGIN ERROR");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $id.$format, $file, FTP_BINARY);
    return $id;
}
upload("https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg", "912198");
?>
```

Comment: Prueba si entra bien en modo pasivo: `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die ("No se pudo pasar a modo pasivo");`

Comment: No se me había ocurrido, pero ese es elproblema, no se puede cambiar a modo pasivo.